# Why won't node zero execute some of the write statements to a log file

Tags: fortran, mpi, stdout, gfortran, openmpi

I have a production job where I use two nodes (0=master and 1=slave) via OPENMPI and all the threads on each node via OPENMP.

I submit the job on the master.
Job opens a disk file on master to log some info.  ( I see same file is opened on slave as well during the run)

I have statements like

```
write(lu,*) 'pid=',pid,' some text'
```

and

```
write(6, *) 'pid=',pid,' some text'
```

one after the other.  (unit 6 is the stdout -screen- in gfortran).
I see on screen that both statements are printed one after the other ( pid=0 and pid=1 ).
Strangely enough  most (not all) of master prints (pid=0) on the log file are absent.

This is puzzling.  I would like to learn the rule. I thought both master and slave share the logfile.

I have a host file with two hosts each requesting 32 threads ( via slots and max-slots commands )  and I am running the following command as a script

```
miprun --hostfile hostfile --map-by node:pe32  myexecutable
```

I will appreciate if some expert can shed light on the issue.

Comment: If you have multiple processes writing to a file via standard Fortran I/O mechanisms the result is not well defined and anything can happen - including losing I/O from some of the processes. The only sane way to guarantee coherency is to write to separate files or use MPI I/O, either directly or indirectly via a library that employs it (e.g. netcdf, HDF5, adios)

Comment: both processes share the same file, but not the same file descriptor. So it is very likely they are both writing at the same offset and hence one is overwriting the other.